# Loading of documents in Windows Explorer takes long time

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, documents, files-folders

Recently, my Windows Explorer is really slow whereby a green loading bar is visible for a long time.

I tried multiple options such as:

- a refresh via the task manager
- rebuilding index
- clear explorer history (+launching folder windows in a separate process)
- uncheck "Allow files in this folder to have contents indexed in addition to file properties"
- msconfig > uncheck "Windows Search" (this option is not visible anymore in my System Configuration either)

but none of these options work. As a result of this problem, I cannot create new folders or whatsoever as the explorer seems to freeze.

I wonder what other steps can be taken to fix this loading problem.

Sources used so far:

- [Displaying directory content is extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896322/displaying-directory-content-is-extremely-slow)
- [Fix Windows Explorer Slow Folder Loading Problems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIws_uU16ko&list=WL&index=1)
- [how to fix file explorer open very slow or stuck in Windows 10 (100% works)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnhiKSQ5Nmg&list=WL&index=2)

Comment: What are you system specs? Run checks on your drives, report the SMART status. Disable or  uninstall any  storage tools that may present in Explorer (OneDrive, Google Drive, Mega, etc). check your Antivirus software.

Comment: Look also tor apps with 32-bit shell context extensions and replace these with 64-bit versions.

Comment: 1. Check in Task Manager, Details tab, what might be using CPU when opening Explorer. 2. Check if disk is running out of space. 3. Are some files offline, e.g., in cloud storage? 4. Are you using third-party antimalware (not Windows Defender) that might be scanning each folder as you open it? 5. Are you **previewing** documents in Explorer, which would be a major cause of slowdown.

Comment: Reinstalling OneDrive and pausing the app worked for me.